# Copy all selected items from ListView1 to ListView2

Tags: delphi, listview

How to copy multiple items from TListView to another. Right now im doing it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.CopyToRightClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  selected: TListItem;
  addItems: TListItem;
begin
  saveChanges.Visible := false;
  selected := deviceList.Selected;
  addItems := selectedDevicesList.Items.Add;
  addItems.Assign(selected);
end;
```

But this way only one selected item get copied. Is there a way to copy all selected items?

Comment: We call it "moving" when it disappears from the source.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ListView2.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
      if ListView1.Items[i].Selected then
        ListView2.Items.Add.Assign(ListView1.Items[i]);
  finally
    ListView2.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

to *copy* every selected list view item in `ListView1` to `ListView2`.

You can do

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListView2.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      for i := ListView1.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
        if ListView1.Items[i].Selected then
        begin
          ListView2.Items.Add.Assign(ListView1.Items[i]);
          ListView1.Items[i].Delete;
        end;
    finally
      ListView2.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

to *move* every selected list view item in `ListView1` to `ListView2`.

(This works well in moderately-sized lists. In larger lists, when you need to do something for every selected item, iterating over all items and checking the `Selected` property is way too slow. Instead, you should use a `while` loop with `GetNextItem` with `isSelected`.)

Comment: Thanks, moving every selected item to another TListView was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: I am getting an error syntax here `ListView2.Items.BeginUpdate;`. Is BeginUpdate already deprecated? same also with `.Selected`, `.Assign`, `.EndUpdate`.

Comment: @RickyBelmont: No, this code works in the latest Delphi version. Nothing has been changed. Are you sure your are creating a VCL application and not a FMX application? This Q and A is only about VCL; FMX is a completely different thing.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I see. Its for VCL only. I am actually creating for FMX. Thanks so much for getting back. Appreciate it. Cheers!