# How to Drag and Drop an Item from one ListView to another

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-xe3, tlistview

i'm having troubles trying to select an ítem from one ListView, and adding it to another ListView. I thought about :

- A simple **Drag and Drop** feature.

or

- Selecting the **index** and storing each **sub-ítem** in **variables**, then adding it to the other ListView.

In the end, i just need to be able to move data from A to B, but never worked with this kind of things, so im quite lost.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Drag and drop is easy enough to implement. Start by reading the documentation for TListView.

Comment: Related, [Copy all selected items from ListView1 to ListView2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5924443/576719).

Comment: Does this question still need a sloution?

Comment: Don't worry, @JensBorrisholt i got it done base on the previous comments, it was kind of an useless question due to a lack of research and a bit of a rush.

Comment: Since no answers will be forecoming and the OP already stated he solved the problem, I voted to close this.